# Role in loopback not working properly getting error 401

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

Hello I'm new to loopback and I'm stucked on the Role creation and use.So basically what I'm trying to do is to create 2 roles and based on these roles I want to restrict some users to access some resources.The problem is that on every attempt to `get` some information from the api I'm getting this

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 401,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Authorization Required",
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
    "stack": "Error: Authorization Required\n    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\battle-horse\\battle-horse\\node_modules\\loopback\\lib\\application.js:433:21\n    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\battle-horse\\battle-horse\\node_modules\\loopback\\lib\\model.js:359:7\n    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\battle-horse\\battle-horse\\node_modules\\loopback\\common\\models\\acl.js:536:16\n    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\battle-horse\\battle-horse\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:3888:9\n    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\battle-horse\\battle-horse\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:473:16\n    at iteratorCallback (C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\battle-horse\\battle-horse\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:1064:13)\n    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\battle-horse\\battle-horse\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:969:16\n    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\battle-horse\\battle-horse\\node_modules\\async\\dist\\async.js:3885:13\n    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\battle-horse\\battle-horse\\node_modules\\loopback\\common\\models\\acl.js:518:17\n    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\battle-horse\\battle-horse\\node_modules\\loopback\\common\\models\\role.js:447:21\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)"
  }
}
```

In my application I have 2 models:

````
1.Client (which extends build in User Model) and has role ```bs_client```
2.Admin(which also extends the build in User Model)
````

Note that these models were created using loopback cli and has no relationship created yet.

```
lb model
```

I'm using Mongodb as database and here is my datasource file

```
  "mongodb": {
    "host": "",
    "port": 0,
    "url": "mongodb+srv://general:234234@#/#@##@?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "database": "database",
    "password": "password",
    "name": "mongodb",
    "user": "general",
    "useNewUrlParser": true,
    "includeSubDomains": true,
    "useUnifiedTopology": true,
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
```

It seems that the data is being added correctly in my collections (`Role`, `Rolemapping`, `Client` and `Access Token`).

I'm assigning role to each client dynamically upon creation  using this

```
 Client.observe('after save', function setRole(ctx, next) {

    if (ctx.instance) {
      if (ctx.isNewInstance) {
        // look up role based on type
        //
        app.models.Role.find({where: {name: 'bs_client'}}, function(err, role) {
          if (err) { return console.log(err); }
          if (role) {

            app.models.RoleMapping.create({
              principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.User,
              principalId: ctx.instance.id,
              roleId: role.id,
            }, function(err, roleMapping) {
              if (err) { return console.log(err); }

              console.log('User assigned RoleID ' + role.id + ' (' + ctx.instance.type + ')');
            });
          };
        });
      }
    } next();
  });
```

and here is my `model-config.json`

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb",
    "public": false
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb",
    "public": true,
    "options": {
      "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
    }
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb",
    "public": true
  },
  "Email": {
    "dataSource": "Email"
  },
  "Client": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb",
    "public": true
  },
}
```

and in `client.json`

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "CLIENT",
      "principalId": "bs_client",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "CLIENT",
      "principalId": "bs_client",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "CLIENT",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "CLIENT",
      "principalId": "bs_client",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
```

Following https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-property-reference.html, everything should be working fine, why I'm not able to retrieve "clients" using the configuration above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to turn on debug to get the basic info about how the app sees the user that is making the request and which ACL rules are applied. To do so, before you start the app you need to export variable `DEBUG=loopback:security:*` and then start the app. You will see in logs that there are all the above rules and you can check what is the result of them.

Comment: Hello Neil, in my opinion, your problem is not related to roles, but to the fact that the client did not perform the login on the server. (or it is also possible in queries you do not pass an authorization token obtained after login). https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Logging-in-users.html

Comment: @akkonrad I'm going to try that and give you the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should look like this everywhere in "acls": "principalType": "ROLE",

example ACL:

```
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: It works ! can you explain to me what I was doing wrong? In my opinion the docs is not well documented. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Neil, I looked at the example here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html